# Can't use window in React.js with server side rendering (SSR)

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering

I'm trying to use SSR with my React app, and I'm struggling to use window as it is only available on client side. Because of that, I tried the below.

```
if (typeof window === "undefined" ? {} : window.innerWidth >= 768) {
  windowScrollTop =
    typeof window === "undefined" ? {} : window.pageYOffset / 3;
  } else {
    windowScrollTop = 0;
}
```

By doing that, it's working, but the screen blinks every time accessing each page. I think it's because sever side is accessed, and window is assigned empty from `typeof window === "undefined" ? {} : ...`,. When client side is accessed, window is available. I guess that's why the screen blinks.

Is there a way to solve this problem? I've been hosted the website with some sample code on a testing server. Does anyone know how to handle `window` issue?

Comment: What are you trying to achive? Scroll to the top?

Comment: Not only `scrollToTop`, but I also need `innerWidth`, `pageYOffset`, `width`, and so on. I need pretty many attributes from `window`

Answer (score 0):

I have an SSR app and checks if the server or the client is rendering like this. However Im not sure if this is best practise but it does the job for me.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import SomeImportedComponent from "../SomeImportedComponent";

// Check if server or client is rendering
const hasWindow = (typeof window !== 'undefined') ? true : false;

class MyComponent extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            const options = {
                innerWidth: hasWindow ? window.innerWidth : null,
                pageYOffset: hasWindow ? window.pageYOffset : null,
            }
            return(
                <SomeImportedComponent {...options} />
            )
        );
    }
}

export default MyComponent;
```

Comment: Should I do that in the root component of the application?

Comment: It depends. If you only need to access the global window object in a single route you could use the code above in a component. However if you need window in multiple routes I would refactor the code above to a Higher Order Component

Comment: Hmm, I tried your way, but still when I access the main page, it blinks. Doesn't it happen you? If it doesn't, is it because of something else?

Comment: I think the flickering is not because of `window` object from the browser. It seems like some configuration issue between client and server. D

Comment: Some people said it could happen when using JSS. I use Material-UI. If the flickering doesn't happen to you, can you tell what CSS framework you're using?